# Unable to add all labels using amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

As per image I am getting only label on first and third column how can I get labels in all columns? Below I have attached an image.

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var chart;

var chartData = [ {
  "month": "JAN",
  "scores": 200,
  "color": "#CD0D74"
}, {
  "month": "FEB",
  "scores": 700,
  "color": "#FF6600"
}, {
  "month": "MAR",
  "scores": 800,
  "color": "#FCD202"
}, {
  "month": "APR",
  "scores": 990,
  "color": "#04D215"
} ];


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv1", {
  "theme": "light",
  type: "serial",
  dataProvider: chartData,
  categoryField: "month",
  "startDuration": 1,
  categoryAxis: {
    labelRotation: 90,
    gridPosition: "start"
  },


  graphs: [ {

    valueField: "scores",
    colorField: "color",
    type: "column",
    lineAlpha: 0.1,
    fillAlphas: 1
  } ],

  chartCursor: {
    cursorAlpha: 0,
    zoomable: false,
    categoryBalloonEnabled: false
  },
  export: {
    enabled: true
  }
} );
</script>
```

Here is **HTML Code:**

```
<div id="chartdiv1"></div>
```

**Graph Image**

[image: Here is **Graph image:**]

Please help me out to solve this . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested your code in JSFiddle and it is showing all the labels but it is having different chartdata with the example in your image.

https://jsfiddle.net/hfqcvauv/

CSS added for the graph to show

```
#chartdiv1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Based on the example in image, probably because the month is not inserted for second and fourth chartdata?